# How to make web scraping in multiple pages with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to make web scraping using Selenium in all pages of the website below, but, until now, I could make it only in the first page. I also put data on a Pandas dataframe. How can I do this operation in all pages of this website? For now, I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import pandas as pd 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Users/Usuario/.spyder-py3/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/ofertas")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

tituloProduto = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('promotion-item__title')
precoProduto = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('promotion-item__price')
df = pd.DataFrame()

produtos = []

for x in tituloProduto:
    produtos.append(x.text)
    
preco = []

for x in price:
    preco.append(x.text)
    
df['produto'] = produtos
df['preco'] = preco

df.head()    


                    produto                          preco

Furadeira Parafusadeira Com Impacto 20v 2 Bate...  R$ 34232

Sony Playstation 4 Slim 1tb Mega Pack: Ghost O...  R$ 2.549

Tablet Galaxy A7 Lite T225 4g Ram 64gb Grafite...  R$ 1.199

Smart Tv Philco Ptv55q20snbl Dled 4k 55 110v/220v  R$ 2.799

Nintendo Switch 32gb Standard Cor Vermelho-néo...  R$ 2.349
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the website you want to scrape has 209 pages in total and can be accessed with the page number: `https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/ofertas?page=2`, so it should be not too difficult.

One thing you can do is to loop 209 times for getting the data from each page. A better approach would be to identify the "next page" button and loop until it's unavailable, but simply using the given page number (209) is easier, so will use that.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r".../chromedriver.exe")

...

# Initialize outside the loop
preco = []
produtos = []

for i in range(209):
  # Parse each page with the code you already have.
  driver.get('https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/ofertas?page=' + str(i))

  # You may have to wait for each page to load
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.sc-2vbwj7-22.blyzsR")))
  
  # If you want to speed things up, you can process them in parallel
  # But you should do this only if it's worth it since it will take development time.

  # Get the variables you want
  tituloProduto = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('promotion-item__title')
  precoProduto = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('promotion-item__price')

  for x in tituloProduto:
    produtos.append(x.text)
  for x in price:
    preco.append(x.text)
  
Store list in DataFrame and do what you want with it.
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you. I thought I had made a comment about your answer, but it seems it was not saved. I found great you have used concatenation to get the next page instead of the click method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r"C:/Users/Usuario/.spyder-py3/chromedriver.exe")

url = "https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/ofertas?page="
df = pd.DataFrame()
produtos = []
preco = []

for i in range(1, 209):
    driver.get(url + str(i))
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    tituloProduto = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('promotion-item__title')
    precoProduto = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('promotion-item__price')

    for x in tituloProduto:
        produtos.append(x.text)

    for x in precoProduto:
        preco.append(x.text)


df['produto'] = produtos
df['preco'] = preco

print(df)
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is find the pagination button and set it to a `next_page` variable like so:

```
next_page = response.xpath('XPATH HERE').css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

and then call it like so:

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```